# How to run "knife configure --initial ..." non-interactively?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I would like to run the `knife configure --initial` command without it prompting me for any user input.

So far I have this:

```
knife configure --initial --server-url https://chefserver.example.com --user workstation-user --admin-client-name admin --admin-client-key /home/ec2-user/chef-repo/.chef/admin.pem --validation-client-name chef-validator --validation-key /home/ec2-user/chef-repo/.chef/chef-validator.pem --repository /home/ec2-user/chef-repo
```

However it is still prompting me for:

```
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
Where should I put the config file? [/home/ec2-user/.chef/knife.rb]
```

And the default is not acceptable - I want it in `/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb`. If I try using the `--config` switch it complains that the `knife.rb` file doesn't exist, so obviously it is trying to read from it, not write to it.

It is also prompting me for the password for the new user:

```
Creating initial API user...
Please enter a password for the new user:
```

Any ideas how I can pass these two values into the command so the command runs non-interactively to completion?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just write the parametrized `knife.rb` where you need it?

Comment: Why not just write the `knife.rb` as a template?

Comment: The command does other things apart from writing the knife.rb file, like generating the client key which I also need

Comment: Craig - did you ever get an answer that worked for you? Thanks, Martin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would suffice your needs but the following command would work just fine.

```
knife cookbook upload helloworld -c /home/ec2-user/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb
```

You need have this file available "/home/ec2-user/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb" before you run the above command and knife.rb will have all the chef-server specific information.